# How to define an accessor in model where the field name contains a number?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to define an accessor in my User model for a field which already exists. This field is called `address_line_1` in my DB. However because the field name contains a number, I am unsure of how to get Laravel to recognise there is an underscore after 'line.'

Usually to define an underscore, you would camel case but in this case you can't. I have checked the Laravel documentation however this issue is not mentioned. Below is my code currently:

```
public function getAddressLine1Attribute($value){
    return empty($value) ? '' : decrypt($value);
}
```

I have also tried the function name `getAddress_Line_1Attribute` and `getAddressLine_1Attribute` but this does not work.

How can I get around this?

Comment: So when you use `$model->address_line_1` it’s not decyptying it?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards If address_line_1 is empty, it will not attempt to decrypt it. The issue I am having is that I cannot get this attribute to work as I cannot get the attribute to recognise `address_line_1`. I could get around this by making an attribute called `address_line_one` and specifically accessing `address_line_1` that way but i prefer just overriding the current field.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards I have similar attributes throughout the user model (e.g. `zip_code` which works fine as the field does not contain a number in its name.

Comment: No worries, was just trying to establish that you are using `address_line_1` to print it in your view, and not `getAddress_Line_1`. Have you tried `getAddressLine_1Attribute` as the method name?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Edit: no, that did not work. For testing purpose, i added `return "test";` to see if the field is even being overridden but it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel 5.7 calls this function to check if the get mutator exists:

```
 /**
 * Determine if a get mutator exists for an attribute.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasGetMutator($key)
{
    return method_exists($this, 'get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute');
}
```

`'get'.Str::studly('address_line_1').'Attribute' === 'getAddressLine1Attribute'`

So it seems your method name is correct.

Comment: Yes that seems to be working now, no idea what went wrong before, however thanks for the confirmation that this is the correct way.

Comment: Just did the same test and also got `getAddressLine1Attribute`.